# dpkg: error processing package sendmail-base

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, 18.10

I upgraded to 18.10. Now I have a problem with **apt**. It seems to be a problem with the **sendmail-base** package:

```
sudo apt autoremove 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up sendmail-base (8.15.2-11) ...
Saving current /etc/mail/sendmail.mc,cf to /var/backups
update-inetd: warning: cannot add service, /etc/inetd.conf does not exist
update-inetd: warning: cannot add service, /etc/inetd.conf does not exist
update-inetd: warning: cannot add service, /etc/inetd.conf does not exist
update-inetd: error: --group is only relevant with --add
dpkg: error processing package sendmail-base (--configure):
 installed sendmail-base package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sendmail-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
sudo apt remove sendmail-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sendmail-base
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 867 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 650513 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing sendmail-base (8.15.2-11) ...
update-inetd: error: --group is only relevant with --add
dpkg: error processing package sendmail-base (--remove):
 installed sendmail-base package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 255
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sendmail-base
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: I found a [forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/linux.debian.user/wWbAI4TuvxA/H0ukikkDAwAJ) where they tell me to change a line in the deb file. But I don't konw how to do this

Comment: I have the same problem exactly... How did you fix this?

Comment: I "cheated" my system a bit. Then the remove worked, but i got havier problems with dpkg.

Comment: I tried installing postfix but that didnt help, then a null MTA and that didnt help...

Comment: The Problem lies in this line of the **prerm** file: [![geany screenshot of prerm script][1]][1]

So I changed the mod of /usr/sbin/update-inetd so the line won't be executed. After that you shuld change the mod back. Then I got some problems with the statoverride file, which you may perhaps delete the affected lines.

So run this as sudo (without any Guarantees)
`
chmod a-x /usr/sbin/update-inetd;
apt purge sendmail-base;
chmod a+x /usr/sbin/update-inetd;
cd /var/lib/dpkg/;
cp statoverride statoverride_org;
nano statoverride;
`


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8X4O.png

Comment: I followed advice in that link you provided to edit prerm file and managed to uninstall `sendmail-base` and `sendmail-bin` and now everything works. Thanks.

Comment: How do you edit a prerm file? I didn't managed to do it. Feel free to write an answer directly.

Comment: I added my solution. BTW I found the prerm file using `sudo find  / -name sendmail-base.prerm`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84854/discussion-between-boba-fit-and-lonix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar errors: `update-inetd: error: --group is only relevant with --add`.

So I followed advice in [the link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/linux.debian.user/wWbAI4TuvxA/H0ukikkDAwAJ) OP gave above.

I did this:

- edited sendmail's pre-removal script `/var/lib/dpkg/info/sendmail-base.prerm` accordingly (depends on the error you're getting) ...I removed `--group MAIL` from that problem line, was almost at the top of the file
- uninstalled `sendmail-base` and `sendmail-bin` (though this may be unnecessary... I had so many errors relate to sendmail that I just nuked it... don't need it on my ubuntu desktop anyway)
- installed `lsb-invalid-mta` which is a fake MTA (will avoid problems later on with apps that want an MTA) - only necessary if sendmail was removed above

Now apt is upgrading properly again!